# how to locate a input field after label that contains another tags like italic or strong for some text only

Tags: selenium, xpath

```
<label>Please <strong>help</strong> me out</label>
```

for this i tried XPath

```
.//label[text()="Please help me out"]/following-sibling::input
```

and also tried

```
.//label[contains(text(), "Please help me out"]/following-sibling::input
```

I tried searching but didn't get the exact one.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take a minute to read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Share your html code or link

Comment: its the code how it looks (i cant share exact as it confidential) <div class="form-group">
<label>
Please:
<i>(enter name and if multiple separe with '|')</i>
<i class="fa fa-asterisk text-cad-red text-top"/>
</label>
<input class="form-control ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-invalid" name="xxxxxx" placeholder="Please enter important names" value="" type="text"/>
</div>

Comment: @Nagasatish Stop posting code here, add it to your question.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the attribute of the input self to locator it.
xpath:

```
//input[@placeholder='Please enter important names']
```

css selector:

```
input[placeholder='Please enter important names']
```

Or with lable assist in xpath:

```
//div[label[contains(text(), 'enter name and if multiple separe with')]]/input
```